# Private Bitbucket package dependency in R package

Tags: r, bitbucket, devtools

**Summary**

When creating a package, I can list CRAN dependencies in the `Depends` list in the `DESCRIPTION` file.  [This documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/vignettes/dependencies.html) outlines how to list Bitbucket dependencies, eg. `Remotes: bitbucket::sulab/mygene.r@default`.

However, I don't know how to do this when authentication is needed to access the repository.

**Attempt**

I've tried putting the following code into the main `packagename.R` file.  The function contents work fine as a snippet at the top of a standalone script:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  otherPackageVersion <- "1.0"
  if (suppressWarnings(suppressPackageStartupMessages(require("otherPackageName", quietly = TRUE, character.only = TRUE)))) {
    if (installed.packages()[installed.packages()[,"Package"] == "otherPackageName", "Version"] != otherPackageVersion) {
      remove.packages("otherPackage")
      devtools::install_bitbucket(sprintf("bitbucketUser/otherPackageName@%s", otherPackageVersion), auth_token = Sys.getenv("BITBUCKET_PAT"))
    }
  } else {
    devtools::install_bitbucket(sprintf("bitbucketUser/otherPackageName@%s", otherPackageVersion), auth_token = Sys.getenv("BITBUCKET_PAT"))
  }
}
```

but R CMD check fails saying it cannot be loaded after hanging for a while:

```
checking whether package ‘packageName’ can be installed ... ERROR
Installation failed.
```

**Further Detail**

The version of `devtools` I have loaded is `1.12.0.9000` (see [this Github thread](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/pull/1220)) which I installed using `devtools::install_github("hadley/devtools#1220")`.  This allows me to install private Bitbucket R packages using an [App Password](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2016/06/06/app-passwords-bitbucket-cloud/) stored in an environment variable, rather than committing my username/password in plaintext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not be possible until [this](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/pull/1220) (a pull request using Bitbucket PATs) is merged into the devtools package.

EDIT: Checking in on this many years later, it's sorted for me by the current version of devtools (2.4.3) using a BitBucket [App Password](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/) with Repo Read/Write and Project Read/Write permissions.